# Creating a video from data of server-side script

Tags: c, arrays, video, ffmpeg, ppm

My plan is to display the data that a server-side script generates in a video displayable on my web page. So far my approach is the following:

1. A three dimensional integer array in a C script is use to accumulate the image data. Dimensions are width, breadth and color (R, G and B).
2. The array is written to a ppm-file.
3. The next picture is accumulated and written and so on.
4. With ffmpeg a script merges the ppm-files to a mp4-video.

Basically this works, but of course faster would be nicer. I would appreciate proposals for fundamentally different approaches as well as help on the following details:

- Is there a file format simple as ppm that uses the HEX code for colors instead of triplets? This would reduce the size of my array as well a the number of write operations.
- Do I loose much time if I print every single value to the file with an fprintf operation instead of accumulating lines into a string? Or do compilers optimize this kind of sequences of writes?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider splitting your post into multiple questions and showing us what code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the required length of the video, animated gif might be a lot easier than a video format. You might want to have a look at the gif-Animation library on github https://extrapixel.github.io/gif-animation/

To the other (more C-related) questions:
*fprintf()* does **formatted** output, which is definitely slower than binary output, thus the ppm (text) format is not specifically known for speed. You may want to look for a binary format (such as .gif above) and a matching library for that format. Should be much faster.

*fprintf()* **buffers** the output, so, apart from adding extra overhead, accumulating your data into a string would not be much faster.

EDIT: Given the size and running time you mentioned, your best bet is probably writing to a simple binary pixel format that ffmpeg is able to digest - .XWD or .PNG might be a good choice, as there are well-tested libraries available that allow you to draw to and store a device-dependant bitmap drawn by you to such files.

A binary format simply has to store much less data than an ASCII-based one - given that a byte is a byte in binary and at least two (maybe more according to format) in ASCII. And the conversion takes time....

Comment: Thank you very much. The length should come to something like 5 minutes with a resolution of probably 640x320. This will depend in part on how well the output can be produced. So I think GIF is probably not an option. I will look into binary output. PPM is very convenient, because I generate the picture pixel by pixel, though about 90% will be backgound of the same color. Only the "interesting" parts are drawn pixel by pixel.